# When converting a factor into a date, I get NA as values

Tags: r, date

I have a data set with bike share information for 2011 and 2012. The date variable is a factor and is displayed as follows: 2011-01-31 (YYYY-MM-DD). I need to split the data set so it contains all 2011 data and only the first half of 2012.

To do this, I want to convert the date variable from factor to date with this command:

```
hw3 = read.csv("bikeshare.csv")
hw3$date = as.Date(hw3$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

When I check the class with:

```
class(hw3$date)
```

I can see that the factor was converted to date, however all my values were changed to NA not dates. **What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks!

Comment: According to the information given in your question, you used the wrong format.  A reproducible example would be totes amazing.

Comment: Just do `as.Date(hw3$date)`. You converting from the correct format to a wrong one. Also, please read `?strptime` in order to get some idea on how formats work in R.

Answer (score -1):

You have to rearrange the order of the year, month and date to `"%Y-%m-%d"` just like it appears in your data, and separate them with `-` instead of `/`

```
sapply(hw3, class)
    ride     date 
"factor" "factor"


  hw3
      ride       date
    1    1 2011-01-31
    2    2 2011-02-01
    3    3 2011-02-02

hw3$date <- as.Date(hw3$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
sapply(hw3, class)
    ride     date 
"factor"   "Date"
```